# the Portal Super User and Portal Super Reader accounts

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Do the Portal Super User and Portal Super Reader accounts need to be configured on both the main **Web App** and the **My Site Web App**?

Currently configured only on our main Web App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have to configure this for MySite as well. Object cache configuration required when you have the site collections with Publishing feature on it. Publishing feature option is available for MySite as well. So you have to configure the object cache( super user and super reader.).

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer.  So would I configure those users on every Web App I create?  Seems like it should be done for every Web App then.

Comment: as a best practice, it should be on every web app otherwise you will see warnings in the logs...

Comment: My pleasure, always happy to help others...waiting for up vote.